# Resize listener for Draw2d Touch

Tags: javascript, draw2d-js

Forgive me if this is a dumb question, I'm a newbie with Draw2d Touch (http://www.draw2d.org/). I need to attach a listener to a Rectangle to notify me when the Rectangle is being resized. I have searched the API but I haven't found anything helpful.

I thought that it could be located in DragDropEditPolicy but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you solved the question yet? If not then the [JSON Example](http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc/#!/example/io_json_basic) should give you a hint:

You can add a event listener:

```
canvas.getCommandStack().addEventListener(function(e){
    if(e.isPostChangeEvent()){
    // displayJSON(canvas); OR call your resize-handler-method
    }
});
```

This you get after the resize is done (something like onMouseUpEvent)

Or you can overwrite the repaint method (which is inheritet by all the shapes.